# request.POST.get() gives None in django

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-requests

I have an ajax call and I caught the request using pdb. **request.POST** gives me the following value:

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"layer_id":1,"status":"True"}': [u'']}>
```

But **request.POST.get('status')** gives **None**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending form-encoded data, so `request.POST` is useless. Use `request.body`.

Comment: but request.body is a string @Daniel

Comment: Yes, it's a JSON string. So use `json.loads()`.